# getting minimum value in a recordset field without Looping

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007 and writing a macro in VBA.
"Analyze" subroutine is passed a recordset rev_rec. This recordset has two fields "PeriodNo" (Integer) and "Revenue"(double).
 Minrev is a variable where I have to store the minimum value of "Revenue" field. The code that I am using is below.

```
    Public Sub Analyze(rev_rec As DAO.Recordset)
    Dim Minrev As Double
    rev_rec.MoveFirst
    Minrev = rev_rec("Revenue")
    While Not rev_rec.EOF
    If rev_rec("Revenue") < Minrev Then
    Minrev = rev_rec("Revenue")
    End If
    rev_rec.MoveNext
    Wend
    rev_rec.MoveFirst
    .
    .
    .
    End Sub
```

I tried using DMin() with recordset but am not able to find a way to do that. Is there a way to do this without using any kind of loop?

Comment: I think your best bet is to build a new recordset using a SQL statement that only retrieves one record, the one with the minimum for the desired period. Another option is, you could open this particular recordset with the Order By on the Revenue column Ascending. This way you would know that the smallest value will be in the first record.

Comment: @HK1 I do not see what is wrong with that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to build a new recordset using a SQL statement that only retrieves one record, the one with the minimum for the desired period. Another option is, you could open this particular recordset with the Order By on the Revenue column Ascending. This way you would know that the smallest value will be in the first record.

Andy Brown's suggestion of using DMin should also work. It's actually an idea very similar to my first suggestion.

Comment: Order By "Revenue" seems to be a good idea and solves my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing a recordset.  If you just had the table or query name (or SQL statement), you could just use DMIN.  Eg:

```
   MinRev = DMIN("Revenue","TableOrQueryNameInQuotes","")
```

The third argument can be used to set some criteria.  For example:

```
 MinRev = DMIN("Revenue","TableOrQueryNameInQuotes","PeriodNo > 5")
```

Be warned, however, that the functions starting with D (DMIN, DLOOKUP, DSUM) run very slowly, although if you've got less than about 10,000 records you won't notice this.

Comment: the problem with it is that I want to pass a recordset only because other data in the recordset is also used and finding the minimum revenue is only a part of the logic.